# Botão reset para controle de tamanho de fonte (acessibilidade)

Tags: javascript, front-end

Bom dia,

Estou utilizando este código para aumentar e diminuir a fonte, queria saber como posso fazer para quando clicar em um terceiro botão (A) ele voltar ao tamanho padrão da fonte, também preciso travar e permitir clicar no botão de aumentar e diminuir apenas 3 vezes.

```js
var $btnAumentar = $("#btnAumentar");
var $btnReset = $("#btnAumentar");
var $btnDiminuir = $("#btnDiminuir");
var $elemento = $("body").find("*");
var fonts = [];

console.log($btnAumentar);

function obterTamanhoFonte() {
  for (var i = 0; i < $elemento.length; i++) {
    fonts.push(parseFloat($elemento.eq(i).css('font-size')));
  }
}

obterTamanhoFonte();
$btnAumentar.on('click', function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < $elemento.length; i++) {
    ++fonts[i];
    $elemento.eq(i).css('font-size', fonts[i]);
  }
});

$btnDiminuir.on('click', function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < $elemento.length; i++) {
    --fonts[i];
    $elemento.eq(i).css('font-size', fonts[i]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="text-right myContainer d-print-none d-none d-lg-block">  
    <button class="btn btn-primary mr-2 mt-2" type="button" id="btnDiminuir">A-</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary mr-2 mt-2 normal" type="button" id="btnReset">A</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary mr-2 mt-2" type="button" id="btnAumentar">A+</button>
  </div>


  <div class="banner-conteudo_txt">
    <h1 data-aos="fade-up-right" class="titulo-web-aulas cor-fundo aos-init aos-animate" tabindex="6">Tema base
    </h1>
      <h2 data-aos="fade" class="tx-branco mb-4 mt-2 subtitulo-web-aulas aos-init aos-animate" tabindex="7">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </h2>
    <p data-aos="fade" class="descricao-web-aulas mt-0 aos-init aos-animate" tabindex="8">Unidade 0 - Seção 0</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Creio que existem duas variáveis apontando pro mesmo botão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça outra array para guardar o valor original, guarde esse valor nela junto da primeira coleção de dados para a array fonts, e então faça a mesma lógica.

```js
var $btnAumentar = $("#btnAumentar");
var $btnReset = $("#btnReset");
var $btnDiminuir = $("#btnDiminuir");
var $elemento = $("body").find("*");
var fonts = [];
var reset = [];

(function obterTamanhoFonte() {
  for (var i = 0; i < $elemento.length; i++) {
    fonts.push(parseFloat($elemento.eq(i).css('font-size')));
    reset.push(parseFloat($elemento.eq(i).css('font-size')));
  }
})()

$btnAumentar.on('click', function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < $elemento.length; i++) {
    ++fonts[i];
    $elemento.eq(i).css('font-size', fonts[i]);
  }
});

$btnDiminuir.on('click', function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < $elemento.length; i++) {
    --fonts[i];
    $elemento.eq(i).css('font-size', fonts[i]);
  }
});

$btnReset.on('click', function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < $elemento.length; i++) {
    $elemento.eq(i).css('font-size', reset[i]);
    fonts[i] = reset[i];
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="text-right myContainer d-print-none d-none d-lg-block">  
    <button class="btn btn-primary mr-2 mt-2" type="button" id="btnDiminuir">A-</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary mr-2 mt-2 normal" type="button" id="btnReset">A</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary mr-2 mt-2" type="button" id="btnAumentar">A+</button>
  </div>


  <div class="banner-conteudo_txt">
    <h1 data-aos="fade-up-right" class="titulo-web-aulas cor-fundo aos-init aos-animate" tabindex="6">Tema base
    </h1>
      <h2 data-aos="fade" class="tx-branco mb-4 mt-2 subtitulo-web-aulas aos-init aos-animate" tabindex="7">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </h2>
    <p data-aos="fade" class="descricao-web-aulas mt-0 aos-init aos-animate" tabindex="8">Unidade 0 - Seção 0</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Não tem muito segredo, você podia ter pensado nisso sozinho, fez a maior parte do trabalho.

Comment: Obrigada Máttheus Spoo eu estava quase chegando neste resultado.

Comment: Eu acabei de editar e adicionar uma linha na função do reset, tinha me esquecido de um detalhe, dê uma olhada.

Comment: O meu tinha dado o mesmo problema quando eu clicava para diminuir ele diminuía mais pegava a informação do maior que estava, faltava este detalhe. Obrigada pela ajuda.

Comment: @MáttheusSpoo será que conseguiríamos salvar o estado do tamanho das fontes em um cookie para não precisar ficar mudando a cada página?